# .first() operator affects other subscriptions

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Example code:

```
const test1$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
const test2$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)

// This subscription need to get every value continuously
const firstSub = test2$
  .do(val => console.log('Service: ', val))
  .subscribe()

// This subscription need to get only first value and stop
const secondSub = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(test1$, test2$)
  .do(val => console.log('Method: ', val))
  .first()
  .subscribe()
```

- **First subscription** starts right after app startup.
- **Second subscription** started by click event (so it could run a few times).

When I use either `.first()` or `.take(1)` operator, somehow first subscription get affected by it too, and stops getting values.

How can I change that behavior to still get values from first subscription, while only get one value from the second subscription and stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a bug in the library when you use an empty (`undefined`) with `subscribe()`.

This is being addressed by:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2238

In the meantime if you update your code like so, things will work as expected.

```
const test1$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
const test2$ = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)

// This subscription need to get every value continuously
const firstSub = test2$
  .do(val => console.log('Service: ', val))
  .subscribe({})

// This subscription need to get only first value and stop
const secondSub = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(test1$, test2$)
  .do(val => console.log('Method: ', val))
  .first()
  .subscribe({})
```

Comment: Thank you. That explains strange Rx behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like using .subscribe() without any callbacks changes the `.first()` operator behavior.

If I pass any `next` callback in `.subscribe()` method, `.first()` operator will work properly.

For example, in `secondSub` change

```
.subscribe()
```

to

```
.subscribe(test => console.log('Method: ', test))
```